# Always have at least one button selected in button group

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a function that ensures there is always at least 1 button selected in my button group. It contains 2 buttons, and if one button is deselected and leaves both buttons deselected, I want to select the opposite button. The problem I am facing is that I can deselect both buttons, then on the following button click both buttons become selected:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/AvcGfNSrEH)

Button Group:

```
<div class="container" style=" padding-top: 25px">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="one">One</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" id="two">Two</button>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#one").click(function() {

    if (!($("#one").hasClass("active")) && !($("#two").hasClass("active"))){

        $("#two").addClass("active");
    }


});

$("#two").click(function() {

    if (!($("#one").hasClass("active")) && !($("#two").hasClass("active"))){

        $("#one").addClass("active");
    }


});
```

**Clarifying:** I want there to always be *at least* one button `active`.

Comment: Isn't there something out if the box in Bootstrap to do this? Styled radio buttons for example?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul that will not work for what I am trying to do I don't think.

Comment: If you find my answer is useful for you mark it as correct answer. it will be useful for other users

Comment: @Jagadeesh your answer does not even work, don't get ahead of yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind side effects and state:

```
var twoIsActive = true;
var oneIsActive = false;

$("#one").click(function() {
    oneIsActive = !oneIsActive;

  if(!oneIsActive && !twoIsActive){
    twoIsActive = true;
    $("#two").addClass("active");

  }
});

$("#two").click(function() {
    twoIsActive = !twoIsActive;
    if (!oneIsActive && !twoIsActive){
        oneIsActive = true;
        $("#one").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

All this does is internally track the state of the buttons (selected, not selected) and given your conditions flips the appropriate button.

http://www.bootply.com/l14oRAS7iG

Answer (score 1):

You only consider the situation where the user clicks on a activated button. Try the following:

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    if (!($("#one").hasClass("active")) && !($("#two").hasClass("active"))){

        $("#two").addClass("active");
    }

});

$("#two").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    if (!($("#one").hasClass("active")) && !($("#two").hasClass("active"))){

        $("#one").addClass("active");
    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LKtYF/

Comment: It seems to work on fiddle, button bootply has a different affect? http://www.bootply.com/fj3cD94fhP

Comment: It does seem to me there is something wrong with bootply. Events are triggered but .toogleClass() does not apply changes to elements properly on bootply

Answer (score 0):

Modify your JQuery as the event for click for first button checks if both do not have class `active` but the second one does.

```
$("#one").click(function() {

    if (!($("#one").hasClass("active"))){//change in condition

        $("#two").addClass("active");
        $("#one").removeClass("active");
    }


});

$("#two").click(function() {

    if (!($("#one").hasClass("active"))){

        $("#one").addClass("active");
        $("#otwo


});
```

Comment: @JordanD see the edit. BTW its not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: What information can I add to make it more clear? I will try to change how I explain the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style=" padding-top: 25px">
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="one">One</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" id="two">Two</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Find the closest div of current button and remove active class for all elements. and add class to current element

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.btn').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).blur(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
});
```

here is working demo http://www.bootply.com/21QfRtg0Tk  this is working as you expect. once check it

Comment: That demo does not work, once I deselect `two` nothing else can be selected.

Comment: I updated my code. actually there should be .btn-group i created another demo and updated link

Comment: problem with bootply.com it doesnt saved my changes

Comment: Same problem, there are states where buttons are not selected.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/WaQpkpewpZ did u check this demo. at a time only one button is becoming active

Comment: But it does not force at least one button to be selected, which is the problem.

Comment: now check this demo. always it will be one button will be active. even if you click on anywhere on document. http://www.bootply.com/21QfRtg0Tk let me know